# PHP MariaDB Pivot Table with dynamic Header and Sub Header

Tags: php, html, mysql, mariadb

I want to create report from database, here is my table

tbl_alokasi

| id_alokasi | nama_alokasi |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pemerataan |
| 2 | Khusus |
| n | etc... |

tbl_akun

| id_akun | nama_akun |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pajak |
| 2 | Retribusi |
| 3 | Lainnya |
| n | etc... |

tbl_penerima

| id_penerima | nama_penerima |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Asep |
| 2 | Ujang |
| n | etc... |

tbl_rincian

| id_rincian | id_penerima | id_alokasi | id_akun | nominal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2000 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1000 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2000 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 500 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 100 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 500 |

all table is dynamic value.

here is what i want with the report,
main header table is dynamic with sub header is dynamic too.
[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlRgN.png)

here database query, save in stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `cetak_view`()
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( "SUM(CASE WHEN id_alokasi = ", ar.id_alokasi, " AND id_akun = ", ar.id_akun ," THEN nominal ELSE 0 END) AS 'alokasi_",ar.id_alokasi,"_akun_", ar.id_akun, "'" ) ) INTO @SQL 
FROM
    tbl_rincian ar;

SET @SQL3 = CONCAT( "SELECT ar.id_penerima, d.nama_penerima,", @SQL, " FROM tbl_rincian ar LEFT JOIN tbl_penerima d ON d.id_penerima = ar.id_penerima GROUP BY ar.id_penerima" );

PREPARE stmt 
FROM
    @SQL3;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

result:
[result] https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtW5V.png

PHP Code

```
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_port = '3306';
    $db_name = 'db_appsimple';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    if (!$conn) {
      die('Error. MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $query = \mysqli_query($conn, 'call cetak_view()');
    $result = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
    ";

    foreach ($result[0] as $key => $value) {
      echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
    }
    echo " 
        </tr>
    </table>";
```

i dont know how to created dynamic header

Comment: Please show us a bit what you tried. SO Is not a freelancer website we won't do the code for you. Doing it in one mysql query is do-able but will be a bit difficult, your best bet is to do it using both queries and PHP.

Comment: Just adding a report does not describe what you are trying to achieve, please be more precise.. For example For table tbl_rincian Given  id_penerima when (condition) then get sum of tbl_penerima/nama_penerima

Comment: Sorry Sir.
I have edit the questions with sql query and php script. i spend 4 days for solution, but not find one, anyone please advice me, example script for creating dynamic header it would be help.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a solution.
here is code what I have used in real project

**query database in stored procedure**:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `cetak_dbh_rencana_rinci`(
IN jenis_dbh INT(2),
IN alokasi_dbh INT (16),
IN skpd INT(8),
IN tahun_r INT(4)
)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( "SUM(CASE WHEN id_alokasi_dbh = ", alokasi_dbh ," AND id_akun = ", ar.id_akun, "  THEN nominal_rencana ELSE 0 END) AS '" ,alokasi_dbh, "_" , ar.kode_akun,"'" ) )
    INTO @SQL 
FROM
    dbh_alokasi_rencana ar;
    
SET @SQL2 = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( "SUM(CASE WHEN id_alokasi_dbh = ", alokasi_dbh, " THEN nominal_rencana ELSE 0 END) AS jmlalokasi") ) 
    INTO @SQL2 
FROM
    dbh_alokasi_rencana;
-- 
SET @SQL3 = CONCAT( "SELECT ar.id_desa, d.nama_desa, ar.id_alokasi_dbh, ", @SQL,"," , @SQL2, " FROM dbh_alokasi_rencana ar LEFT JOIN tbl_desa d ON d.id_desa = ar.id_desa WHERE ar.id_jenis_dbh =",jenis_dbh ," AND id_skpd = ", skpd ," AND  tahun_realisasi=",tahun_r, " AND id_alokasi_dbh =", alokasi_dbh , " GROUP BY ar.id_desa
ORDER BY ar.id_alokasi_dbh, ar.id_desa
" );
-- SELECT @SQL3;
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL3;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

**result of query :**
[result_db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krBc0.png)

**Controller**

```
  public function cetakRencanaRinci($idJenis, $idSkpd, $tahun)
  {
    $desa = $this->desa->getDesa();
    return \view('dbh.cetak_rencana_rinciv3', \compact('desa', 'idJenis', 'idSkpd', 'tahun'));
  }
```

**the view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Laporan Rencana DBH</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
      padding: 1px;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 11px;
    }

    table {
      /* border: 1px solid black; */
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .bawah {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .kiri {
      border-left: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .kanan {
      border-right: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .atas {
      border-top: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .text-kanan {
      text-align: right;
    }

    .text_blok {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<?php
$alokasi = DB::table('dbh_alokasi')
  ->where('id_jenis_dbh', $idJenis)
  ->where('id_skpd', $idSkpd)
  ->where('tahun_realisasi', $tahun)
  ->get();
$header1 = '';
$header2 = '';
$idAlokasi = '';


// $desa = DB::table('tbl_desa')->get();
?>

<body>
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <?php
        $i_al = 0;
        foreach ($alokasi as $al) {
          $kodeAkun = '';
          $akun = DB::table('dbh_alokasi_akun')
            ->where('id_alokasi_dbh', $al->id_alokasi_dbh)
            ->where('id_jenis_dbh', $idJenis)
            ->where('id_skpd', $idSkpd)
            ->where('tahun_realisasi', $tahun)
            ->get();
          echo '<td style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0 !important;">';
          echo '<table style="width:100%">';

          echo '<tr>';
          if ($i_al == 0) {
            echo '<th rowspan="2" class="kiri atas bawah kanan">No.</th>';
            echo '<th rowspan="2" class="atas bawah kanan">Kecamatan</th>';
            echo '<th rowspan="2" class="atas bawah kanan">Desa</th>';
          }
          if (count($akun) != 0) {
            echo '<th colspan="' . count($akun) . '" class="atas bawah kanan">' . $al->nama_alokasi . '</th>';
            echo '<th rowspan="2" class="atas bawah kanan">JUMLAH</th>';
            echo '<tr>';
          }
          foreach ($akun as $ak) {
            $kodeAkun .= $al->id_alokasi_dbh . '_' . $ak->kode_akun . '-';
            echo  '<th class="bawah kanan">' . $ak->nama_akun . '</th>';
          }
          echo '</tr>';
          $explodeKodeAkun = explode("-", substr($kodeAkun, 0, -1));
          $rencana =  DB::select('call cetak_dbh_rencana_rinci(?,?,?,?)', [$idJenis, $al->id_alokasi_dbh, $idSkpd, $tahun]);
          $no = 1;
          foreach ($desa as $d) {
            echo '<tr>';
            if ($i_al == 0) {
              echo '<td class="kiri bawah kanan">' . $no++ . '</td>';
              echo '<td class="kiri bawah kanan">' . $d->nama_kecamatan . '</td>';
              echo '<td class="kiri bawah kanan">' . $d->nama_desa . '</td>';
            }
            $sum = 0;
            foreach ($rencana as $rp) {
              for ($i = 0; $i < count($explodeKodeAkun); $i++) {
                if ($rp->id_alokasi_dbh == $al->id_alokasi_dbh &&  $rp->id_desa == $d->id_desa  && property_exists($rp, $explodeKodeAkun[$i])) {
                  echo '<td class="kiri bawah text-kanan">';
                  echo number_format($rp->{$explodeKodeAkun[$i]}, 0, ',', '.');
                  echo '</td>';
                  $sum += $rp->{$explodeKodeAkun[$i]};
                }
              }
            }
            if (count($akun) != 0) {
              echo '<td class="kiri kanan bawah text-kanan text_blok">' . number_format($sum, 0, ',', '.') . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
          }
          echo '</table>';
          echo '</td>';
          $i_al++;
        }
        ?>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

**and here the final result**
[final result html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqwoJ.png)

for now this is the best solution for me.